# PostgreSQL sytax - DROP DTB

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, syntax-error

I created database with name -encoding=UTF-8 (miss clicked)

nothing worked to remove databese.

```
\l
     name           |  owner  | Encoding | Collate     | Ctype  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    -encoding=UTF-8 | test1   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8

DROP DATABASE -encoding=UTF-8;
ERROR: syntax error at near "-"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE -encoding=UTF-8;
```

Do i have any chance to drop database or i have to reinstall PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers with special characters need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
DROP DATABASE "-encoding=UTF-8";
```

For details on how to use identifiers, please see the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

The name might contain leading or trailing whitepace. To get a properly quoted identifier, you can use this query:

```
select quote_ident(datname)
from pg_database;
```

Comment: problem : ERROR: database "-encoding=UTF-8" does not exist

Comment: Then apparently the database has a different name. Maybe some trailing or leading spaces. Try: `"    -encoding=UTF-8"`

Comment: select quote_ident ('-encoding=UTF-8');

return :

    "-encoding=UTF-8"   /* no visible spaces or diferent name

Comment: @novice: of course there is no visible space because there is none in the string literal you used. Use the query I added.

Comment: i tryed 
" -encoding=UTF-8"; " -encoding=UTF-8 "; still ERROR: database does not exits

Comment: @novice: Again: run the query I added to my answer to get a correctly quoted identifier.

Comment: select quote_ident ('-encoding=UTF-8') from pg_database; return 7 same rows with "-encoding=UTF-8"

Comment: @novice **again**: use the query I added in my answer. Do ***not*** use a string literal, use the column name from `pg_database`

Comment: results: template1, template2, posgres, dtb1,dtb2, dtb3, "-encoding=UTF-8" (7 rows)

Answer (score 0):

`-` isn't usually a legal character in object names. If you want to use it, you should protect the name with quotes (`"`):

```
DROP DATABASE "-encoding=UTF-8";
```